# p-value for website errors inside a time window

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, p-value

I'm finishing up a project to migrate a website to a new technology stack. I want to make a data-driven decision on the impact to the website's error rate.

I have data like this:

```
Type: Before
Count: 100

Type: After
Count: 10

Type: Before
Count: 50

Type: After
Count: 20
```

These counts are a sum of all errors on the website during a one hour time range. I want to be able to say that the number of errors are reduced, by how much, and a p-value to say how confident I am this observation wasn't by chance. Since the website is inherently noisy due to high traffic, we will need a large sample size to see through the noise - the question is which mehod of determining a p-value do I use?

My first stab at this was using a 2 tailed t-test, with equal variance between before and after. I am referencing this biology stackexchange question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/deciding-between-chi-square-and-t-test

My thinking is a t-test is more appropriate than a chi-square test due to the count of errors being continuous, rather than being some threshold I can categorize under a value.. On the other hand, I could use chi-square if I compare before counts to after counts..

What is the most appropriate test to use in this situation? I don't think count of errors will be normally distributed since there can never be negative errors.. but does that mean the t-test is invalid in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand You have a table, where the first column is Before/After and the second is Count. If it is so just try bootstrap.

1) calculate delta_obs=mean(Before)-mean(After);
2) shuffle first column
3) calculate delta_shuffle=mean(Before)-mean(After);
4) go to step 2 and collect many delta_shuffle

calculate the probability as number of (delta_obs>delta_shuffle)/(number of shuffling steps+1)